# Multiply two lines together

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Excuse me , I had a strange question :). In algebraic geometry, a quadratic expression can be written as the product of two different linear equations, for example: y = x² + 3x - 4 can be factored as y = (x+4)(x-1). (x+4) and (x-1) are two parallel line and do not intersect.

geometrically, I don't understand why their product is a quadratic expression. I can understand algebraically that the multiplication of their terms forms a quadratic expression, but I don't understand it geometrically. I would appreciate it if you could guide me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic

Comment: Note that (x^2 + 3x - 4) = 0 if and only if at least one of its factors (x + 4) and (x - 1) equals 0. Therefore the locus of the quadratic equation above is just the union of the locus of x+4 = 0 and the locus of x-1 = 0.

Comment: PS  It doesn't really make sense to say that x+4 or x-1 is a line. What is a line is the locus of the *equation* x+4 = 0, as is the locus of the equation x-1 = 0.

Comment: Try drawing both lines on the same graph, then multiply (x + 4) and (x + 1) for say x = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 and then plot the points. Join up the points and you will have a quadratic.